# GDAL - Command Line vs. Spyder (Python) Functionality

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff, osgeo

I am trying to retrieve information from a GeoTiff using the GDAL API in Python (Spyder).  Within Anaconda I have my base environment which contains gdal v2.3.3, but I also created a virtual environment with gdal v3.0.2 since this version of GDAL can read GeoTiffs that can be classified as "BigTiffs" (> 4GB).

When I run 'gdalinfo filename.tif' from the Anaconda terminal within my virtual environment, I get coordinate system information output that starts with:

```
Coordinate System is: PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 16N", BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84", DATUM["World Geodetic    
System 1984", etc..
```

I can also obtain this same data when I run 'print(gdal.Info("filename.tif"))' within Spyder which is also configured for my virtual environment:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr, ogr
print(gdal.VersionInfo())  # outputs 3000200 (i.e. v3.0.2)
print(gdal.Info('filename.tif'))  # outputs same data as Anaconda terminal
```

However, when I attempt to obtain GeoTiff information using 'gdal.Open("filename.tif")' within Spyder and invoke other GDAL functions I obtain GeoTiff data that does not appear compatible with gdal v3.0.2:

```
dem = gdal.Open('filename.tif')
print(dem.GetProjection())  # outputs PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 16N",GEOGCS["WGS 84", etc...
```

For the "GetProjection()" function, for example, I need the output to show "PROJCRS" and not "PROJCS".  I need the GDAL commands within Spyder to be compatible with v3.0.2, but they seem to be returning outputs compatible with v2.3.3.  Is there something else I may be missing when invoking the GDAL API?